# capybara+rspec erase form text fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

Using capybara+rspec how can i compile a form with empty fields?
I'm testing an edit resource page, so i have a compiled form and want to clean its text fields. This is a partial of test:

```
context "when submitting" do
        before { visit edit_post_path(post) }
        it {should have_content('Editing')}
        it {current_path.should == edit_post_path(post)}

        describe "whit invalid information" do
          before do
            fill_in "post[title]",    :with => "" #not working
            fill_in "post[body]", :with => "" #not working
            click_button "update"
          end
          it {current_path.should == edit_post_path(post)}
        end

        describe "whit valid information" do
          before do
            fill_in "post[title]",    with: "some"
            fill_in "post[body]", with: "some"
            click_button "update"
          end
          it {should have_content('some')}
          it {should have_content('some')}
          it {current_path.should == post_path(post)}

        end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Check manually actual ID/name/label of relevant field in generated HTML of Edit-page via Chrome:InspectElement of Firefox:Firebug. High chances they are  different to "post[title]".

**UPD.** Try to fill in empty strings manually on the page. Does it work fine? I mean error displayed and the route is correct. Firing "Update"-button and getting an error you're not on the `edit_post_path` anymore. It happens bc in case of unsuccessful `@post.update` you're rendering `Post#edit`-view from `Post#update` action.

Comment: the describe "whit valid information" works, so the post[title] and post[body] are ok.

Answer (score -1):

Likely problem is that `post[title]` and `post[body]` are the names of the fields, and not the IDs.

Also, something you might want to look into to make your tests a little more rigorous: capybara has a builtin `within` function that yields a block in which you can perform more actions. Check out the documentation on the front page of the gem page: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara. It would probably look something like:

```
describe "whit invalid information" do
  before do
    within("#post") do
      fill_in "title", :with => ""
      fill_in "body", :with => ""
      click_button "update"
    end
  end
  it {current_path.should == edit_post_path(post)}
end
```